# unity - texture scroll speed with gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine, scroll, textures, offset

I have a board in unity3D and I have a cube onto board. Board has got texture and texture offset changing by Y coordinate so it seems like moving backward. Cube should move also with same speed as board's offset but I couldn't set the same speed between them.

My board scroll code :

```
public class moveBoard : MonoBehaviour
{

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{

    this.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", new Vector2(0, -1 * Time.time));
}
}
```

And my cube move code :

```
public class moveTus : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject board;
float offsetY = 0f;
// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    this.transform.Translate(Vector3.back * -10 * Time.deltaTime) ;
}
}
```

So I need to move the cube with same speed of the board's offset speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include a public speed variable into both scripts.

`public class moveBoard : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed=1;
    void Update ()
    {
        this.GetComponent().material.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", new Vector2(0, -1 * Time.deltaTime * speed * UserOptions.speed));
    }
}`

public class moveTus : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed=1;
    void Update ()
    {
        this.transform.Translate(Vector3.back * -10 * Time.deltaTime * **speed** * UserOptions.speed) ;
    }
}

During runtime try to sync by changing any of these speed variables values manually in Editor Inspector. After you find out a fine tune between them, apply these values in design time.

Comment: You are true but the user will be able to change speed variables in game options. So there should be a perfect rate between them otherwise I cannot find it with my eyes.

Comment: You will need a static variable somewhere to hold the speed selected by the user. You cold multiply both speeds by that. Anyway you'll have to find this sync before.

Comment: Even you found a sync speed before, if you change the optionable speed, the sync variable must be changed otherwise we wiill see the difference again.

Comment: What I mean is a third (static) variable to be exposed to the user. This variable should multiply both speeds I suggested. If it is sync once, it will be good forever. I updated the code, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same functionality today. So here is my code

```
    List<Vector2> uvs = new List<Vector2>();
    groundMesh.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.GetUVs( 0 , uvs ); // get uv coordinates

    float min = float.MaxValue;
    float max = float.MinValue;

    foreach ( var item in uvs ) // find min and max
    {
        if ( item.x > max )
        {
            max = item.x;
        }

        if ( item.x < min )
        {
            min = item.x;
        }
    }

    groundUV_X = Mathf.Abs( min - max ); // find absolute value
```

My Fixed Update Code :

```
 var v = groundMaterial.GetTextureOffset( "_MainTex" ); // get current offset
        groundMaterial.SetTextureOffset( "_MainTex" , new Vector2( v.x + ( speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime * groundUV_X) * (1.0f / groundMesh.bounds.size.z) , v.y ) ); 
// multiply speed by groundUV_X which is total distance between x coordinates
// multiply by world size (normalized total distance)
```

Get min and max uv coordinate (is x coordinate in my case) and multiply it by speed.
Since we need texture size in woorld coordinate (which is bounds.size.z in my case)
normalize it by 1. and boom we got synced coordinates.

If anyone cant get it to work just let me know. I can add more details.

Comment: could you please add, how to get `groundMesh` and `groundMaterial`...?